# Can't connect to ethernet with ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: networking, system-installation, ethernet, 22.04

I recently did a clean install of Ubuntu server 22.04, but ethernet doesn't work. During installation, it shows the ethernet controller but I can only choose "continue without network". After installation, ethernet only sometimes works for a few seconds after boot. On Ubuntu server 20 and 21, this did not happen.

How can I fix this? Because there isn't internet, I can't install anything to help.

Comment: A lot more details is needed.

Comment: Please also be precise; Ubuntu Core 20 (or *year* product server releases) are different products to those using the *year.month* format; and no *year* product is released on *odd* years (ie. no Ubuntu Core 21 exists).  20 != 20.04

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ip a` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.